# reverse engineering the Nord Lead 4 control board

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, sampling, reverse-engineering

I am reverse engineering a synthesizer named nord lead 4. I want to tap in between the control board and mainboard which has the microprocessor.

i didn’t started with the powered on analysis but i am making a map of the connections and getting to know the IC’s.

I figured out all the pins of the 26 pin cable between the control board(which has potentiometers and two leg switches and 7 segment led displays etc.).

This board has also the IC’s that i am interested 3 ADC ‘s (max1039) a mux/demux(hc4052) 2 octal bus trancievers(lc245a) and probably for the seven segmented displays 6 flipflop IC’s(hct374) and one demux(lvc138a).

I also figured out all the selects and connection between the ADC’s and the mux/demux hc4052. This is mostly all i understand from topology until now.

My question is about the switches. There are around 34 switches in this control board(the ones you press with your finger they are momentary switches) they have two legs when you press there is a connection created between the two legs ofcourse.

These switctches are distributed to 8 busses of the octal tranciever(lc245a) and those busses sent to the other board which has the microprocessor. So multiple switches are on the same bus. Do you have an idea how this machine reads them and know which is which? Does this topology seem familiar to you?

Thank you very much Please tell me if you need more info.

*i hope i put the right tags to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify and match functions to pins.  Only the OEM designer knows how they are read into memory.  Usually by a chip select to enable bus side read.
From ‘138

8 switches need 3 bits to address.
32 switches need 5 bits to address.
38 switches need 6 bits to address. Or 8 bits as done here.

This can be done with 3 bits to ‘138 and 3 more bits from CPU using matrix array if switches are not grounded.  This uses typical low to select 1 of 8 rows and “1” to bias 5 Columns with diodes or in software input open cct or output=1. Thus 3+5 software switches = 8 bits from CPU during port  8 address bits then read switches like RAM. Or any variation of this.

CPU inputs 3 but address to ‘138 decoder to select 1 of 8 latches in a sequential manner as fast as it needs to.  Classic bus MUX.

Comment: as i guess these switches are for giving logic high or low but if you have more than one switch at the same bus? How would you know which one is pressed? I must be missing some part in the circuit there seems to be no mux or demux between the switch and bus.

Comment: See http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/How_Key_Matrices_Works/

Comment: wow what a beautiful explanation about key matrices. I didn’t know this technique. I will check the device acordingly

Comment: In 1975 we used a 1:16 decoder and latches and logic on MC6800 to read and write 96 LEDs and 96 switches and 3 digit LED display. For SCADA command centre.

Comment: What if i have 34 switches, then according to the key matrix technique there should be 8 columns and 5 rows, because with 8 and 4 i can only read 32 switches but to read 34 i need another row, or is there another way to achieve this? Because the fifth row will be only added for 2 switches instead of 8.

Comment: Rows and columns may be reversed. Eight lines decoded from three bits and five orthogonal lines adds up to eight bits for 40 switches max

Comment: Glad to share in your career

Comment: This btw is the best explanation so far. http://blog.komar.be/how-to-make-a-keyboard-the-matrix/

Comment: It always irks me that NKRO fails to be leading edge after 3K and becomes trailing edge resulting in tyopgrhaphic dislexia ...like that.